# When I click this <a> link it will post back to my ASP.NET method. How can I do that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

When I press this link it will post back to my method. How can I do that?

```
<li runat="server" onclick="log_out" >
    <a onclick="log_out" runat="server" href="LogIn.aspx" ><i class="icon_key_alt"></i> Log Out</a>
</li>
```

This is my method:

```
public void log_out(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int employeeid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["employeeid"].ToString());
        cl.log_out_activity(Convert.ToInt32(employeeid));
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a `HyperLink` so you can set the `NavigateUrl` like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
        NavigateUrl="~Login.aspx">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
```

Then in the `Page_Load` of `LogIn.aspx` you will do whatever you need to.

If you want to go to a specific method then use `LinkButton` because it has `OnClick` property like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton 
  ID="Button1" 
  OnClick="log_out"
  runat="server"
  Text="Submit" />
```

If you want to do go to a specific method with `HyperLink`, you then have to use javascript. You can see [this](https://gchandra.wordpress.com/2007/09/27/call-javascript-function-inside/) article on how to do it. Personally I would just use `LinkButton`: